# Getting the error: float object cannot be interpreted as an integer, when trying to print the prime factors of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print a list of all the prime factors of a number, suppose if the number is 56, then 2, 2, 2,7  are prime factors.

I wrote the following code, but I get the error: float object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Not sure what's wrong with the code. Would appreciate your insights .

```
a=[]

def prime(n):

# Checking for the number of number 2's 

  while(n%2==0):
    a.append(2)
    n= n/2


# Checking for odd prime factors (3,5,7......) 

  for i in range(3,n,2):
    if(n%i==0):
      a.append(i)

  return a


print(prime(56))
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `n//2` (int division) instead of `n/2` (float division).

Answer (score 3):

In the line:

```
 n= n/2
```

You are creating a float. Use integer division instead:

```
n = n // 2
```

Moreover, this code won't give you the prime factors of `n`; not every odd number is a prime number (9, 15, etc.) You are on the right track; take a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/) for a solution that works.